# <th> and <td> inside <tr> Is it a legal HTML code?

Tags: html

```
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th>Default</th>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id=""></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This HTML code snippet is valid ?

Comment: Why don't you ask http://validator.w3.org/ ?

Comment: Have a look on **[HTML5 <tr> specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element)**, it allows `"Zero or more td, th, and script-supporting elements"` into `<tr>` tags.

Comment: Of course. If you weren't supposed to put `<th>` and `<td>` inside `<tr>`, where else would you put them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing invalid about a table row containing both table heading and table data cells. Semantically, this would usually make sense only if the headings were `scope="row"`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with http://validator.w3.org/.
It does not say that it is wrong.

But however, I have to question the need to mixing it up.

Comment: the <th> and <td> in a <tr>

Comment: Sorry, but that's silly. You are allowed and even *expected* to mix them up in order to semantically describe the table structure. `<th>` even has [an attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/th.html#th.attrs.scope) you can use to say "this header applies to the current row", i.e. all its sibling `<td>`s. It's another thing entirely that many people don't know how and when to do so.

Comment: Lol. I am not saying it's wrong. Just wondering on why he wanted to do so. That's all. Perhaps me "questioning" came out a bit stronger than expected.

Comment: Saying "mixing it up" makes it sound like you think it's wrong.

Comment: Yeah probably I worded it wrong. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be valid HTML.

As far as I can see there is nothing that disallows a th-tag next to a td-tag.

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp

Comment: Please don't reference W3Schools. They are often wrong.

Comment: For HTML5 specifications : http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element

Answer (score -3):

Here is the valid code  : 
You just didn't give the id.

```
  <table>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th>Default</th>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="box"></td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Use this http://validator.w3.org/check  link for checking, Is your HTML code is valid or not